# DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener in Azure Websites

Tags: azure

I have been using Azure Cloud Services the past year and is used to reading my trace logs with Azure Management Studio, with logs being stored in table storage using DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener.

I am confused about starting using azure websites as it seems they are using a diffrent logging structure? Is it not possible to see the trace logs from azure website using azure management studio in the Diagnostic/Trace like i used to with Cloud Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagnostics in azure websites is similar to any web application. DiagnosticsMonitor applies to webroles. In the case of websites, diagnostics need to have a persistent storage and it can be configured in azure management portal.
Check out these posts.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2014/01/29/from-the-mvps-diagnostics-and-logging-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingDiagnosticsTraceLoggingFromTheAzureCommandLinePlusGlimpse.aspx

The logs can be downloaded and analysed locally. I am not sure if the tool that supported webroles  works for this too.

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostics viewer tool for cloud services will not work for Azure Websites, but there is a tool for viewing your Azure Website logs called **Azure Website Log Browser**. It is installed as a [site extensions](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/20/azure-web-sites-extensions/) on your Azure Website.

You can read more about it [here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/).

Comment: thanks. it just surprised me that it was totally different and just needed confirmation that the same tooling that i used to use dont work with azure websites. I swapped back to using cloud services.